# dividing the PHP mail function into seperate tasks, making it more efficent and able to handle a much higher volume of recipients

Tags: php

Say I wanted to send over 10,000 emails to 10,000 different recipients (email addresses) all fetched from a SQL DB, but obviously, I'd have issues using the `mail();` function alone...

So I was thinking, If I separated the task (to send 10,000 emails) into like 100 different tasks, which gets processed every 3 seconds through AJAX.

This is how I'm thinking of dividing the big task into many small ones:

Firstly, check how many recipients in the task (10,000 in this case).

If there are over 100 recipients in the task, begin dividing:

if there are 200 recipients or less, divide the total into 2

or if there are over 200, divide into 3 and so on....

So basically, make sure the total gets divided into separate tasks, with no more then 100 recipients each task...

then store each set of recipients in a SQL db per ROW, along with the users messege and subject and all the other headers and stuff...

Then, an AJAX request runs every 3 seconds, processing one task at a time.

So the END result: I'll have many different tasks in the SQL db pending completion. Where each one will be completed every 3 seconds...

Now I need to know if this really is more efficient and will allow me to use the mail(); to handle a much higher volume?

or will I just be wasting my time?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a mail queue? Create a queue in the database, and just process one by one. This offers an ability to create priorities too. Just run a cron job every minute or so, and send a batch.

And you definitely shouldn't use raw `mail()` function, instead, use a mailing class, for example, http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=phpmailer It takes care of headers, easy attachments, multiple recipients etc.

Comment: Ok then, call the queue script with ajax as you previously stated :)

Answer (score 0):

I would just use [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org) with a spool (queue).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this answers your question but we implemented PHPList at work to handle this. It's open source and allows you to control email lists, throttling, and a wide array of other settings. We have a database of 300,000 users and right now our email list has 12,000. All we have to do is create the email and click send, then over the course of the week it sends the emails out in batches(You can also control this too). If this is something your going to be doing many times to your recipients, I would recommend taking a look at it.